# When i mouseLeave menu i am unable to click somewherre

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have problem with my Menu component. It should works something like this:
OnHover -> menu shows (you can click some item)
OnMouseLeave -> menu should hide

In my case when I mouseLeave i am unable to click something and i need to go to browser toolbar to hide menu which I open on moseLeave to button.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {Button, Toolbar, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
import UserContext from "../../../UserContext";



function PopOverMenu(props) {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    function handleClick(event) {
        if (anchorEl !== event.currentTarget) {
            setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
        }
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            < Button
                aria-owns={anchorEl ? "simple-menu" : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleClick}
                onMouseOver={handleClick}
                onMouseLeave={handleClose}
            >
                <Typography>{user ? user.username : "unknown"}&nbsp;</Typography>
                <Menu
                    id="simple-menu"
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    MenuListProps={{onMouseLeave: handleClose}}
                >
                    <MenuItem onClick={()=>{
                        window.location = '/';
                    }}>
                            Zmena role
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Nastavenia</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={()=>{
                                if (window.confirm("Really Sign out?")) {
                                    window.location = '/';
                                    Auth.signOut();
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            Sign Out
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(PopOverMenu);
```

Comment: You have the `onMouseLeave` event on the button element. So when you move the mouse off the button, then the menu will close

Comment: Yes i know. But i am saying that menu will stay still open after mosueleave the button.

Comment: Oh I see. I think the problem is that the menu element is inserted on the body when you hover on the button. You expect the menu to be inserted as a child of the button. Maybe you could try to add the mouse events to the menu also?

Comment: I tried. But nothing change but thx for trying to help